# Cluster on high dimensional categorical data (Images with keywords)

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, large-data

We're looking for clues to perform a Cluster Analysis in a DB with **+400K images** which have keywords associated to them.
Each image could have from 1 to 30 keywords.
Total **keywords count is +35K**.
Keywords are not assigned with uniform criteria, e.g. one dog image can have `[animal, canine, dog]` and other similar dog picture can have `[dog, friend]`. We will assume that keywords are strong related with images.
We are not expecting to classify all images, but we'll be happy to get about 50% of data in coherent groups.
We have used factor analysis with ordinal data to reduce variables and then perform cluster, but we are a little bit lost in this case.

1. How could we reduce the number of variables (keywords)?
2. How to filter cases (images) that are less likely to be grouped?
3. Is this problem already (publicly) solved?

Comment: What would be a good cluster? I mean, you don't want just random partitions!

Comment: We want groups of images where (most of) keywords (kw) describe (most of) images. <br/> Our first naive attempt was an algorithm which first step was searching for images with same amount and exactly same kw's. Questions appears in second step: Search for images/groups with one kw difference. e.g. If group have 6 kw's, look for images/groups with 5 kw's included in (6 kw group), or images/groups with 7 kw's where (6 kw group) are all included in (7 kw group). <br/> The obvious problem with this approach is what to do with groups with 1, 2 or 3 kw, where one kw makes a big difference.

Comment: For this definition of "clusters", you may want to look at **frequent itemset mining** instead. It's not cluster analysis, but probably what you are looking for: frequently used keyword combinations implicitely also group transactions (= images).

Comment: I've been reading and seems you gave me a good advice :-) . The problem of large amount of items still is present and I am avoiding to make a 35K x 35K matrix. Please tell me if I am wrong: if I look for all distinct groups of keywords assigned to images, will be those _ALL_ my **itemsets**?

Comment: Any combination of keywords is an itemset. There is no notion for disjoint itemsets; this constraint it usually not considered interesting. Usually, one is interested in maximal itemsets, i.e. such that no larger superset of keywords exist that still is frequent.